# Can I describe a Simulink block structure with code?

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

**For example:** I need a block, that consist of `N` UnitDelay blocks. And they should be connected in series. And `N` should be the block parameter.

I was wondering if I can create a block with code, that looks something like this:

```
begin block

UnitDelay unit_delay1
UnitDelay unit_delay2

unit_delay1.input <= block_input
unit_delay2.input <= unit_delay1.output
block_output <= unit_delay2.output

end block
```

---

**The question is about describing a block structure with code. It's not just about unit delay blocks from example.**

Comment: You could use an embedded script and use a "for" loop that gets `N` as an input. In each loop you introduce a delay using `pause()` function. Is there any restriction that prevents you from using an embedded MATLAB script?

Comment: @Omid I have no restriction. Your solution is great for my example. But I was wondering if I could describe block structure, that uses other blocks. (Like in Verilog or VHDL)

Comment: Would the "For Iterator" block help? http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/foriteratorsubsystem.html

Comment: @Omid Not really. Updated question.

Comment: You need to be able to set the number of unit delays, right?

Comment: If that is the case then you can use Simulink command line feature. You can easily add blocks using the command line. I have not used this feature of Simuilink extensively but this is something that you can look into: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/functionlist.html

Comment: You can code a Mask providing `N` as a mask parameter

Comment: @Omid Not exactly that I wanted, but very close. THNX)

Comment: This just came to my mind. If you are looking to have a variable time delay block then this might help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/variabletimedelay.html

You can set it to get an external delay time. Let's say if you want to have N unit delays then you can calculate how much time delay that would be and send that value to the block.

Comment: The [Tapped Delay Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tappeddelay.html) does pretty much what you are asking. It outputs all delayed signals, so you'd just need to select the top signal.  If that doesn't do what you want then you will need to spent time creating a mask for a Subsystem, where the mask uses MATLAB-Simulink API functions (such as [add_block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_block.html)) at initialization to add and configure the blocks that you want in the subsystem.

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like subsystem mask initialization commands will do the work.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to do that? It seems to me a case of "why do something simple when we can do something complicated instead?". There have been a lot of really good suggestions to do what you want with a single block. The mask approach will probably work, but it's a lot of work to set up and get it working properly.

Comment: @am304 My question was not about unit delay blocks. My question was: `Can I describe a Simulink block structure with code?`. I'm planning to make some parameterized blocks, that contains other blocks.

Comment: @Holoceo OK, it wasn't clear to me from the question. The API that Phil Goddard suggested is the way to go. The relevant functions are  listed in the documenation at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/modeling-basics.html.

Comment: @am304 Yep, already started using it. THNX)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is: you can create a masked block with initialization [commands](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/functionlist.html).

Big thanks to [@Omid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3567563/omid) and [@Phil Goddard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1998377/phil-goddard)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "MatSim" here: https://github.com/gave92/Matsim

It's a wrapper that allows for nicer Syntax than using the plain API commands like `add_block`.

```
block = Subsystem()
block_input = block.in(1, {})
unit_delay1 = Delay(block_input)
unit_delay2 = Delay(unit_delay2)
block_output = block.out(1, unit_delay2)
simlayout(sys.handle)
```

Plus, this also does all the nontrivial block placement and layout of the resulting model.

Comment: This is an old question, oopsi